# In Vuetify, VMenu is closing when selecting date in AppDateTimePicker inside it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, menu, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vue theme [Vuexy](https://themeforest.net/item/vuexy-vuejs-html-laravel-admin-dashboard-template/23328599?gclid=CjwKCAjw_aemBhBLEiwAT98FMv3Rjy8zSaOg_MzmjlM6Vh20vwoHpNsbMK2k51eUsiq8bydqGprE1xoC9O4QAvD_BwE) (Vue & Vuetify) & I'm getting an issue with VMenu as it's having an AppDateTimePicker (DatePicker of Vuetify) in it & when selecting date, it's getting closed with menu, How to prevent menu from closing ???

Here's my code

```
<VMenu width="300" height="450" :scrim="true" >
  <template #activator="{ props }" v-slot:activator="{ on: { click } }">
    <VIcon class="cursor-pointer" icon="tabler-settings-plus" v-bind="props" @click="updateEditIndex(indexUpper)"></VIcon>
  </template>
  <VList>
    <VListItem v-for="(item, indexLower) in menuItems" :key="indexLower" :active="false">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-2" v-if="item.type === 'checkbox'">
        <VCheckbox v-model="field[item.value]" :label="item.title" />
        <p class="text-body-2">{{ item.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-2" v-if="item.type === 'textfield'">
       /// Some Input Fields
      </div>
                          
      <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-2" v-if="item.type === 'date'">
        <AppDateTimePicker :label="item.title" placeholder="Pick up the date" v-model="field[item.value]"  />
      </div>
    </VListItem>
  </VList>
</VMenu>
```

I've tried `@click.stop` on Datepicker & `:close-on-content-click="false"` on menu but nothing worked.

Any Help Would be Appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mage to fix this? im having similar issue but with a dialog. When i have a appdatetimepicker inside a dialog it closes the dialog when i select a date

Comment: No, it didn't resolved, I've to use a modal instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make this work.
You can use the prop `persistent` that receives a `boolean`.
This will stop the dialog to close when you select the date but it will also stop de dialog to close when you click outside of itself. If you do this you will notice that there is a quick animation after you select the date, if you don't want that you can use the prop `no-click-animation` that also receives a `boolean`. Example:

```
    <VDialog
      :width="580"
      :model-value="ClickFunction(foo)"
      no-click-animation
      persistent
    ></VDialog
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when I was using `<AppDateTimePicker />` inside a `<VDialog />`.

I fixed it by removing this prop,

```
@update:model-value="dialogModelValueUpdate"
```

From `<VDialog />` component.

*I don't know the exact reason, but it might be because of model-value, a name conflict with model-value inside the*